# Need help with this S-L problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem:
$$\frac{\text{$\delta $u}}{\text{$\delta $t}}=\frac{\delta ^2u}{\text{$\delta
   $x}^2}\text{-u+x(1-x)}$$

The IC are given as:

$$u(0,t)=1$$
$$u_x\text{(1,t)=0}$$
$$\text{u(x,0)=}\frac{3e+1}{\text{Cosh}(1)}\text{Sin(x)-3}e^x$$

My attempt:

Let $$v(x,t)=u(x,t)+u_e (x)$$

Let $$u_e (x)$$ solves $$-u_e+\frac{\delta ^2 U_e}{\text{$\delta $x}^2}+(1-x) x=0$$

The general solution is $$u_e (x)=\text{ACosh} x+\text{BSinh} x-x^2+x-2$$
(by combining the particular solution and complementary solution)

The general solution given by my tutorial is $$u_e(x)=\frac{3e+1}{\text{Cosh}(1)}\text{Sinh(x)-3}e^x+x-x^2-2$$.

Would someone explain to me why the general solution on my tutorial differs from mine? My intuition tells me that the general solution from the tutorial came from the 3rd boundary condition but as far as I understand, the general strategy is to solve for X first since X is a boundary value problem and to do so, we seek boundary conditions for which it is homogenous.

I have been on this problem for 3 whole hours. If someone could assist me in offering a bounty for this question, I'll put all my points for this question.

Using the BC, I found $$\text{3 Cosh[x]+(}\frac{1-3\text{Sinh}[1]}{\text{Cosh}[1]}\text{)Sinh[x]-}x^2\text{+x-2}$$ but this is nothing similar to the solution from my tutorial sheet.

Comment: which boundary conditions are you letting $u_e$ solve? It is not obvious to me what you have tried to get that solution

Comment: @ellya Hi, I begin first by using $$u_e\text{(1,x)=1}$$ followed by $$u(0,t)=1$$
This gives the solution in the last equation of the OP. But I am lost as to how the tutorial solution arrived at another solution.

Comment: I think that's where the problem comes in, you are solving an inhomogeneous problem with inhomogeneous BC's, to do this you split into into two problems: one that has a zero right hand side and non zero boundary conditions, and one that has a non zero right hand side and zero boundary conditions, I will see where this leads and post some kind of answer

Comment: @ellya That's what I did, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: First I solve for 
$$\frac{\delta ^2u_e}{\text{$\delta $x}^2}-u_e\text{+x(1-x)=0}$$
Then, seeing that $$u_e\text{(1,x)=0}$$ has a zero on the RHS, I apply this boundary condition to extract a coefficient.
After which I apply $$u(0,t)=1$$

Which leads to $$\text{3 Cosh[x]+(}\frac{1-3\text{Sinh}[1]}{\text{Cosh}[1]}\text{)Sinh[x]-}x^2\text{+x-2}$$

What have I tried?
reversing the order in which I applied the BCs
expanding and putting the tutorial's solution into respective Cosh and Sinh form to see if it fits my solution(s).
None works.

Comment: Perhaps you only need to use that $\sinh x+\cosh x = e^x$ and $\cosh(1)=(e+1/e)/2$ resp. $\cosh(1)+\sinh(1)=e$ to find the true difference of both proposed solutions.

Comment: Are the boundary conditions correct? For $u(0,0)$ the vertical condition gives the value $1$, the horizontal condition gives the value $-3$. And is it $\sin(x)$ or $\sinh(x)$?

Comment: @LutzL Boundary conditions are correct. As for the matter of Sinh or Sin, it is Sinh(x). Nothing to worry, it was edited long before you worked on rectifying the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put the tutorial solution into a normalized form. Which means either using only hyperbolic functions or expressing everything exponential or hyperbolic in $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.

Aiming for hyperbolic functions, one gets, using $e^x=\cosh(x)+\sinh(x)$,
\begin{align}
u_e(x)&=\frac{3e+1}{\cosh(1)}\sinh(x)-3e^x+x-x^2-2
\\ \\
&=\frac{3\cosh(1)+3\sinh(1)+1}{\cosh(1)}\sinh(x)-3(\cosh(x)+\sinh(x))+x-x^2-2
\\ \\
&=\frac{3\sinh(1)+1}{\cosh(1)}\sinh(x)-3\cosh(x)+x-x^2-2
\end{align} 
which is similar to your solution up to some sign changes. However, the tutorial solution does not even satisfy the boundary condition at $x=0$, which means that it is wrong for the given problem.

Your posted solutions 
$$
u_e(x)=\frac{\sinh(x)+3\cosh(x-1)}{\cosh(1)}+x(1-x)-2
$$
satisfies the ODE and boundary conditions, so it must be correct.

Comment: Which really just means my opportunity cost was 4 hours when I could be doing Physics. Horrible!
How do I give you bounty?